# LetterBoxing in CaptureElement

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have a letterboxing problem on my Lumia 1020.

I use a Stretch Uniform to fill but I can still see those letterboxes:

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="capturePreview" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```